# Table in GridView is using CSS from DetailsView control

Tags: css, asp.net

I am having architectural trouble setting up styles for gridviews and detailsviews.

Our Intranet server is basically a multiple application website. Most reports, and tools are using grid structure, but because they may perform wildly different functions the formatting varies slightly from grid to grid and detail to detail.  I tried to make a dedicated style for each, but I am running into inheritance issues.
For example: I wanted an extra title bar for some Gridviews. 
the Gridview is set up like this:

```
<asp:GridView
            ID="GridView_Links"
            runat="server"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataKeyNames="link_key"
            AllowSorting="True"
            CssClass="GridView"
            GridLines="Vertical"
            EnableModelValidation="True"
            Caption='<table CssClass="GVcaption" ><tr><td>Link Manager</td></tr></table>'
            CaptionAlign="Top"
            OnRowCommand="GridView_Links_RowCommand">
            <FooterStyle CssClass="GridView-Footer" />
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridView-Header" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="GridView-AlternateRow" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="GridView-Row" />
            <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="GridView-SelectedRow" />               
        </asp:GridView>
```

The Details view is referenced the same way for css.
What happens is  the Caption table doesn't get GVcaption applied to it and instead has .DetailsView-CommandRow a, tr:nth-child(1) applied to it.

Here is the css for  it.

```
/*Gridview*/

.GridView {
    border-bottom: solid 3px #335e77;
    border-left: solid 3px #335e77;
    border-right: solid 3px #335e77;
    border-top: solid 1px white;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px #5A6266;
}
.GVcaption table {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    border-right-color: #335e77;
    border-bottom: solid 3px #335e77;
    border-left: solid 3px #335e77;
    width: 100%;
}
.GridView table {
    align-content:center;
    text-align:center;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    border-right-color:#335e77;
    width:100%;
}

.GridView-Header a, th {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: medium;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 3px;
    border-top-color: white;
}

.GridView-Header  tr:nth-column(0) {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
GridView-Header td   { 
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: white;}

.GridView-Row tr td {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    color: black;
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: auto;
    border-right: solid 1px white;

}
.GridView body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    background-color: white;
        padding: 3px;
}

.GridView-SelectedRow tr {
    background-color: #00ff90;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
    align-content: center;

}

.GridView-AlternatingRow tr {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.GridView-Footer tr {
    background-color: #335E77;
    color: black;
    align-content: center;
}

.GridView-Pager {
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid;
    color: black;
    align-content: center;
}

/*DetailsView*/

.DetailsView {
    padding: 3px;
    border: solid #335e77;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: left;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px #5A6266;
}

.DetailsView-Header td, td:nth-child(0) {
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: white;
}

.DetailsView-Footer td, td:nth-child(0) {
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.DetailsView tbody {
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    text-align: left;      

}

.DetailsView-CommandRow a, tr:nth-child(1) {
    background: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid 1px black;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;    
}

/*.DetailsView-Row tr {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: pink;
    text-align: left;   

}*/

.DetailsView-FieldHeader {
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background-color: #335E77;
    border-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
}
.DetailsView tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;    
}
```

If I am setting up the css incorrectly, how should I be doing it?  I did try to use a named element like #GVcaption but it was applying to tables that weren't named, which broke other things on the site (main nav bar) :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it to work. It's not 100% done and there are a few classes that might look strange or repetitive, but I also have some other css that is coming from a global include. The main issue was that I had to target the same elements in 2 different tables, but differently as the table rendered for GridView doesn't render the same for DetailsView.

```
/*Gridview*/



.GridView {
    text-align: center;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px #5A6266;
    align-content:center;
}
    .GridView-Header a:hover {
        background-color: white;
        color: #335e77;
    }

table.Gridvieww-Row tbody, tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: lightgray;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-left: 3px;
    border-right: 0px;
    align-content: center;
}

table.Gridvieww-Row tbody, tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    font-weight: 400;
    border-left: 3px;
    border-right:0px;
    align-content:center;
}

table.GridView-Row tbody, tr, td {
    width: auto;
    align-content:center;    
}

.GridView-Header a{
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
}

.GridView-Header th:last-child {
    border-right-color: #335e77;
}
.GridView-Header th:first-child {
    border-left-color: #335e77;
}
.GridView-Header th, tr:nth-child(0) {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-right-color: white;
    border-top-color: white;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    background-color: #335e77;
    transition: none;
}

.GridView-Header tbody tr   { 
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-color: white;}

tr.GridView-Row tr, td:last-child, a {
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    transition: none;
}

table.Gridvieww-Row tr:nth-child(even), a:hover {
    background-color: #335e77;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
}

    .GridView tbody {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #666;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
}

.GridView-SelectedRow tr {
    background-color: #00ff90;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    align-content: center;

}

.GridView-AlternatingRow tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: deeppink;
}

.GridView-Footer tr {
    background-color: #335E77;
    color: black;
    align-content: center;
}

.GridView-Pager {
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: solid;
    color: black;
    align-content: center;
}

.GridView textarea, input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

#GVcaption {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#GVcaption tbody tr td {
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 16px !important;
    border-right: solid 3px #335e77;
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;
    border-left: solid 1px #335e77;
    border-right: solid 3px #335e77;
    border-top: solid 3px #335e77;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #335e77;
}



/*DetailsView*/

table.DetailsView  {
    border: solid #335e77;
    background-color: transparent;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 1px #5A6266;
    box-shadow: 5px 10px 10px #5A6266;
    align-content: center;
    color: white;
    width: auto;

}

tr.DetailsView-Row td {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.DetailsView-Header td, td:nth-child(0) {
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    border-top-color: #335e77;
    border-left-color: #335e77;
    border-bottom-color: white;
    border-right: 0px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.DetailsView-Footer  td {
    background-color: #335E77;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}

.DetailsView-FieldHeader {
    padding: 5px 5px;
    background-color: #335E77;
    border-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
    color: white;
    text-align: left;

}
.DetailsView tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #DCDCDC;    
}

DetailsView-Footer td, tr:last-child {
    border-top-color: black;
    border-bottom-color: white;
}


.DetailsView textarea, input[type=text] {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```